# Troubleshooting a breaker box - several breakers stopped working

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Most of the outlets in my workshop stopped working last week. My 220V outlet, a dedicated outlet for a compressor, and the garage door are still working. The shop has a dedicated circuit box, which is a GE sub-panel from the main panel at the house.

I unscrewed the front panel and measured the voltages of the 2 buses using my multi-meter and found the right bus measures 120V, but the left one measures around 20V and bounces around. All the breakers connected to the left bus are the ones that stopped working. The box has it's own double pole main breaker rated at 100A.

Could it be that one half of that breaker is bad? What would be the most cost effective way to troubleshoot the problem? I would like to avoid buying all new breakers for the receptacles if that is not the problem.

Comment: I take it these readings were taken at the main lugs of the subpanel, no?

Comment: Yes, one lead on the buses themselves and the other on the ground bar

Comment: Take the reading in the main panel.

Comment: Does everything work in your house?

Comment: @Fiver -- can you open the main panel and take readings from the lugs of the subpanel breaker to ground, please?

Comment: You can measure on the input side of the breaker, right?  Are the voltages stable there?  **Also compare voltages to both ground and neutral**.  They should be *about* the same; if they aren't, that can be a neutral wire break, which is very dangerous.   Find loads in your house labeled for auto-switch multi-voltage 100-240V, and plug at least one into each leg of power, and have it turned on/doing its thing.  That will help expose a neutral problem that may otherwise hide.

Comment: The issue with a neutral problem is that (under load) one leg will be less than 120V and the other leg will be *more than 120V*. That will fry things that only tolerate 120V. That's why I advise connecting only variable-voltage 100-240V loads. Many modern lights (post-2012 tube fluorescent and LED) are that.

Comment: @JACK Yes, everything in the house works.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Measured the input lugs to the main breaker in the sub-panel and one is stable at 121.5V and the other jumps around from 3-20V. I guess that leads to the either the main panel at the house or the line to the shop, right?

Comment: Yup, that sounds right to me.

Comment: So check the voltage at the load side of the breakers in the main panel that feed the sub-panel.